# System Threading Tasks String To String Conversion Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, firebase, asynchronous

I am trying to have photos that are on Firebase downloaded into a listview depending on the CandidateID.

I have a task list linked as the datasource of the listview and a function to retrieve the URL from firebase.

I have tried to add a string in the task list in order to retrieve the URL but I am getting an error message saying I cannot convert system.threading.tasks String to string.

```
    public async Task<string> GetFile(string fileName)
    {      
        return await GlobalVar.firebaseStorage
            .Child("ProfilePhotos")
            .Child(fileName)
            .GetDownloadUrlAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<JobApplication>> GetApplications()
    {
        var canInfo = await GetCandidates();
        return (await GlobalVar.firebaseClient
          .Child("JobApplication")
          .OnceAsync<JobApplication>()).Select(item => new JobApplication
          {

              CandidateID = item.Object.CandidateID,
              ApplicationDate = item.Object.ApplicationDate,
              ApplicationTime = item.Object.ApplicationTime,
              CandidateName = canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).Name + " " + canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).LastName,
              NewCanID = item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1),
              ImageURL = GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")
          }).ToList();
    }
```

I've used the Eval expression in the Image Source, but there is a red line under 'GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")'. Is there anyway I can convert this into a valid string so it can work?

Comment: I tried using await before GetFile but it says it can only be used in an async lambda expression. If I try ToString() after it doesn't return the URL.

Comment: Okay ImageURL = Task.Run(() => GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")).Result seems to work but if there isn't a file it throws up an error. Anyway to catch this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am getting an error message saying I cannot convert system.threading.tasks String to string.

Visual Studio gives you this error because you are trying to assign a `Task<string>` to a `string`, and it's can't find a conversion. `Task<T>` wraps a `T`, and you need to unwrap the `T`. The proper way to unwrap a `T` from a `Task<T>` is by using `await`.

In this case, I think it's easier to break up that huge `return` statement and then you can see what you need to do more clearly:

```
public async Task<List<JobApplication>> GetApplications()
{
  var canInfo = await GetCandidates();
  var jobApplication = await GlobalVar.firebaseClient
          .Child("JobApplication")
          .OnceAsync<JobApplication>();
  return jobApplication.Select(item => new JobApplication
  {
    CandidateID = item.Object.CandidateID,
    ApplicationDate = item.Object.ApplicationDate,
    ApplicationTime = item.Object.ApplicationTime,
    CandidateName = canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).Name + " " + canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).LastName,
    NewCanID = item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1),
    ImageURL = GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg") // error
  }).ToList();
}
```

You need to use `await` on the `Task<string>` returned from `GetFile`, and this requires the lambda passed to `Select` to be `async`.

```
public async Task<List<JobApplication>> GetApplications()
{
  var canInfo = await GetCandidates();
  var jobApplication = await GlobalVar.firebaseClient
          .Child("JobApplication")
          .OnceAsync<JobApplication>();
  return jobApplication.Select(async item => new JobApplication
  {
    CandidateID = item.Object.CandidateID,
    ApplicationDate = item.Object.ApplicationDate,
    ApplicationTime = item.Object.ApplicationTime,
    CandidateName = canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).Name + " " + canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).LastName,
    NewCanID = item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1),
    ImageURL = await GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")
  }).ToList();
  // error: the code is now trying to return Task<List<Task<JobApplication>>>
}
```

Now, you have a sequence of *tasks* returned from `Select`. You can either (asynchronously) wait for them to complete one at a time:

```
public async Task<List<JobApplication>> GetApplications()
{
  var canInfo = await GetCandidates();
  var jobApplication = await GlobalVar.firebaseClient
          .Child("JobApplication")
          .OnceAsync<JobApplication>();
  var result = new List<JobApplication>();
  foreach (var item in jobApplication)
  {
    result.Add(new JobApplication
    {
      CandidateID = item.Object.CandidateID,
      ApplicationDate = item.Object.ApplicationDate,
      ApplicationTime = item.Object.ApplicationTime,
      CandidateName = canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).Name + " " + canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).LastName,
      NewCanID = item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1),
      ImageURL = await GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or, you can start them all simultaneously and then wait for them all to complete:

```
public async Task<List<JobApplication>> GetApplications()
{
  var canInfo = await GetCandidates();
  var jobApplication = await GlobalVar.firebaseClient
          .Child("JobApplication")
          .OnceAsync<JobApplication>();
  var tasks = jobApplication.Select(async item => new JobApplication
  {
    CandidateID = item.Object.CandidateID,
    ApplicationDate = item.Object.ApplicationDate,
    ApplicationTime = item.Object.ApplicationTime,
    CandidateName = canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).Name + " " + canInfo.Find(a => a.CandidateId == item.Object.CandidateID).LastName,
    NewCanID = item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1),
    ImageURL = await GetFile(item.Object.CandidateID.Substring(1) + "-One.jpg")
  }).ToList();
  var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation of how to get around this problem. I'm new to C# so I am still trying to get my head around lots of things but this helped me greatly. I used your first example, and I was able to put my check in to determine whether the file existed online just after the 'for each' line to prevent the error from happening.